# Setting up Subscription based products

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, opp-lineitemschedule

We sell a subscription based product, based on volume pricing/usage, billed at the end of each month.

How would you set that up with products/opps/contracts in SFDC?

Ideally we would have 1 opportunity but I'm open to suggesion...

Answer (score 1):

You would use product schedules and in particular revenue schedule to recognize revenue monthly.

You will have your opportunity and associate the product to the opportunity. This product can have the revenue schedule defined by default which you can tweak if need be.

Comment: even though the actual cost is based on usage, at the end of each month?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at using Zuora.com which is a much more rigorous subscription application.  It does have a salesforce integration to help manage New Opportunities and renewals etc.

Comment: hi @Jason Lawrence in my company already using zuora. But i newly joined in this company and i didn't know about integration and everything.Did you i want to save data from salesforce to zuora. Please provide me any suggestions or relevant posts.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate simplified opportunity (Record Type) for each month of the subscription contract with the estimated amount/volume, then at the end of each month update the Opportunity stage to a closed won stage and update the amount/volumes.

We have used this for annual subscriptions which proves useful for pipeline reporting but could see it being quite time consuming at month end (without an integration) to update multiple Opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the **Encore app** to deal with your subscription sales. Encore is a renewals & subscriptions management app that’s built entirely on Salesforce and uses standard objects - opportunities, products, pricebooks, accounts, etc..

**http://www.kineticgrowth.com/encore-salesforce-renewals-subscriptions-billing/**

Encore automatically creates and emails invoices based on your subscription billing schedule and requirements. In addition, Encore can automatically process recurring payments.  For example, it can automatically charge a customer’s credit card every month.  And Encore can also provide a website/portal where customers can view their accounts on the web and make online payments.

Here's the Encore AppExchange listing:

**https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000007rRGLEA2**

This answer is by Kinetic Growth.  We made Encore as a way to sell subscription products in Salesforce.  Please contact us for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at using Chargebee.com which is a much more rigorous subscription application. 
It does have a salesforce integration to help manage New Opportunities and renewals etc.Also it enables you to set that up with products/opps/contacts in SFDC.
We also have a plug-in which integrates salesforce with chargebee.You can check that out on appexchange using the link:-

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B53dYEAR